# FirefoxOS packaged game loading time

Tags: html, haxe, firefox-os, marketplace, flambe

We are working on a packaged html5 game for the FirefoxOS marketplace.

Our game passes review, except the game shows a black screen before starting. The reviewers said this black screen shows for a very long time. It is my belief that the games wrapper is trying to load **ALL** assets before it shows the game.

The problem is, our game already has internal loaders that load portions of the game assets. Does anybody know how to tell the FirefoxOS packaged html5 app to let the game do all of the loading, so my preloaders can work?

Comment: Hi! More information is needed in order to answer this question. 

* Are you using a specific game toolkit?

* Are you marking your script includes as deferred?

* How are you loading your assets, and what kind of assets are you talking about?

(Sorry for all these edits - hitting <return> keeps submitting!)

Comment: A FirefoxOS app loads all content for a defined `app` index [tag:html] file. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

I also use Flambe. Befor it can display anything, it should load at least the index.html, flambe.js (flambe project loader) and ofcourse main-html.js file (actual game code). From that point you could load other assets to display an actual preloader, but that could also take time. If you use FillSprites then it reduces some time.

But what I mostly do, is adding a simple CSS3 animation (loader) on top of the canvas. I give this html element a certain id, and when I have loaded enough to show the "real" preloader, I remove this CSS loader animation from the DOM. This allows to show a preloader very fast or to load a bit more designed preloader if you wish.